# Unable to load static files with express.js

Tags: node.js, express, static

I've been trying to get CSS files and JS files to work alongside my HTML files with express.js but I am unable to get it to work with the express.static() method but it doesn't work and returns a "Not allowed to load local resource" error.

```
const express = require('express');
const fs = require('fs')
const http = require('http')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')

const app = express();

app.use('/static',express.static("D:\Testing\Chat app(Amber Light)\Public") )

app.get("/", function(req,res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html')
  console.log(req.rawHeaders);
})

app.listen('3000', function(){
  console.log('Code works')
})
```

Comment: Hi, welcome, the tag `static` is off-topic here

Comment: If you use `express.static()`, there is no need to use `__dirname`. Just index.html. I think, however, that spaces in file names can cause problems

Comment: In it's simplest form `app.use(express.static('public'))` will serve your static files from `/path/to/public/`. Read the very clear explanation [here](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html). You only need to use `app.use('/static', express.static(...))` if you app.js file is not on the same filesystem directory and level as your `public` root folder i.e you need to then pass a relative path.